# Mockito: Testing behavior when mock objects cant be injected

Tags: jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, mocking, tdd, mockito

I have a method defined as

```
@Startup
@Singleton
public class PRCConnectionRunner { 

@Inject 
private ServiceStatus status;

private Timer connectorTimer = null;

public void destroy() {
    connectorTimer.cancel();
    status.stopped();
}
}
```

I want to test the behavior of destroy that it calls both stopped and cancel. I can test for stopped easily by injecting a mock object of status as below

```
@Mock
ServiceStatus status;

@InjectMocks
PRCConnectionRunner prcConnection;


@Test
public void destroyShouldCallStatusStop() {
    prcConnection.destroy();
    Mockito.verify(status).stopped();
}
```

However since i cant inject connectorTimer as it is constructed inside the PRCConnectionRunner class, how can i test that the destroy calls cancel() on connectorTimer?

Comment: In general, this is not possible with Mockito (or EasyMock), because each mock object created in the test must be *passed in* somehow into the object under test. To mock objects created/obtained internally, you would need to either use PowerMock in addition to Mockito, or use the JMockit library.

Comment: So am i testing it incorrectly? or is my design incorrect?

Comment: How about just using plain old reflection to set the `Timer` field? That's basically the foundation of how `@Inject` works

Comment: I don't have enough information to say your design is incorrect, or you are testing it incorrectly.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker Even if i injected timer with reflection, how can i verify that the method cancel() was called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use PowerMockito. Its MemberModifier allows setting of private members and you can "inject" timer mock and verify it. In order to use PowerMockito you should annotate the test class by @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class). It should be something like this:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class TestConnectionRunner
    @Mock
    ServiceStatus status;

    @InjectMocks
    PRCConnectionRunner prcConnection;

    @Mock
    Timer timerMock;

    @Test
    public void destroyShouldCallStatusStop() {
        MemberModifier.field(PRCConnectionRunner.class, "connectorTimer").set(prcConnection, timerMock);
        prcConnection.destroy();
        Mockito.verify(status).stopped();
        Mockito.verify(timerMock).cancel();
    }
}
```

You can find some more Mockito/PowerMock examples in this [link](http://www.codepreference.com/2016/04/powermock-mockito-mocking-examples.html)

Comment: What package is MemberModifier in? My eclipse is unable to find it. Also i believed in the last line you meant timerMock instead of connectorTimer?Mockito.verify(connectorTimer).cancel();

Comment: I believe you meant powermock instead of Mockito?

Comment: You are right - I updated the answer (that what happens, when code is not run)